# How to add/subtract Hue, Brigtness or Saturation of a hexadecimal RGB color, using SASS?

Tags: sass

By example, I have a color #3e779d. If I subtract 5 of brightness, I get #396d8f.

I search a method in pure SASS (with function?), not SASS extension (as https://gist.github.com/1932866).

It's possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [RGB function](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgb_functions)s and [HSL functions](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#hsl_functions). They are SASS native.

Comment: thank you! I did not expect all these functions in SASS. 'lighten' appears as the function I need.